# Is it possible to load AWS SSM ARN in Init container and use in the main container

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

How to pass AWS SSM ARN or Access Key and Secret as env variables in init container and then pass the SSM parameters to main container.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a solution like https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-external-secrets

It supports both `SSM Parameter Store` and `AWS Secrets Manager` as backends. Pros of this comparing to init container is that you have a much more narrow scope of pods with an access to SSM. In your case it's every pod (every init container you run), in the case of `kubernetes-external-secrets` it's only one controller pod per cluster. And of course, it gives less boilerplate.

Similar solutions:

- https://github.com/mumoshu/aws-secret-operator
- https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/externalsecret-operator
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/aws-secrets-controller-poc/

Comment: Yes, we followed the same. But we need to have a process where we will call the SSM parameters directly to init container.

Comment: Init container can also mount secrets as env vars, similar to the other containers. Otherwise maybe smth like this: https://github.com/jicowan/secret-sidecar